# Prove that: $\sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{b+c}{a^{2}+bc}\leq \sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{1}{a}$

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials

If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive then $$\sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{b+c}{a^{2}+bc}\leq \sum\limits_{cyc}  \frac{1}{a}$$
The things I have done so far:
$$\frac{b+c}{a^2+bc}\leq \frac{b+c}{2a\sqrt{bc}}=\frac{b}{2a\sqrt{bc}}+\frac{c}{2a\sqrt{bc}}\leq \sqrt{2\left ( \frac{b^2}{4a^2bc}+\frac{c^2}{4a^2bc} \right )}= \sqrt{2\left ( \frac{b^2+c^2}{4a^2bc}\right )}$$
I just make it looks more difficult!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a\geq b\geq c$.

Thus,
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a}-\sum_{cyc}\frac{b+c}{a^2+bc}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)(a-c)}{a^3+abc}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{(b-a)(b-c)}{b^3+abc}+\frac{(c-a)(c-b)}{c^3+abc}=(b-c)\left(\frac{a-c}{c^3+abc}-\frac{a-b}{b^3+abc}\right)\geq0.$$

Comment: @Shizumi Aoki I think your inequality is very nice. Write please your trying,  otherwise this topic will be deleted. Thank you!

Comment: If I typed my trying, wouldn't my topic be deleted?

Comment: @Shizumi Aoki Yes. It's a policy of this forum. If you don't show your trying, the topic will be deleted even if the problem is very beautiful.

Comment: I need time to type my trying for this problem. Is it ok? Please don't delete my topic.

Comment: @Shizumi Aoki Take your time! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

By expanding the statement, the inequality becomes 
$$a^4b^4+b^4c^4+c^4a^4 \geq a^4b^2c^2+b^4c^2a^2+c^4a^2b^2$$
This inequality is same as the popular
$$p^2+q^2+r^2\geq pq + qr + rp$$
In case you do not know how to solve that,
$$p^2+q^2+r^2-pq - qr - rp = \frac{1}{2}(p-q)^2+\frac{1}{2}(q-r)^2+\frac{1}{2}(r-p)^2\geq 0$$

**side note**: btw, this works for your original question as well. There was a constraint $0<a,b,c\leq1$. Assume both sides are multiplied by a non-negative constant $\dfrac{1}{k}$, then left terms become of the form $\dfrac{kb+kc}{k^2a^2+kbkc}$ and the right terms become $\dfrac{1}{ka}$. That indicates if $a, b, c \in (0,1]$ satisfy the inequality, so are $ka, kb, kc$ for any non-negative $k$. In other words, the range constraint does not matter. New constraint would be $a,b,c>0$.

The more you know :)